# Any idea to exit FOR and print a message

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, numbers

```
int liContador1, liContador2, liElse = 0;

    for (liContador1 = 1; liContador1 <= liNumeroB; liContador1++)
    {
        for (liContador2 = liContador1 + 1; liContador2 <= liNumeroB; liContador2++)
        {
            if (NumerosAmigos(liContador1, liContador2))
                printf("\n%d, %d", liContador1, liContador2);

            else
                liElse++; **or what can i do?**
        }
    }

    if (liElse != 0)
        printf("\nThe numbers are not friends.\n");
```

I'm making a program to search the previous amicable numbers to a given value. The program prints the pair of numbers found but need to display a message if no pair of amicable numbers.

The problem is that I can not think on way to do it. I tried with BREAK, continiue, ACCOUNTANTS ..

This is what i was trying:

```
else
                liElse++;
```

**Anyone have any ideas on how I can do to solve this ?.**

Greetings and thank you all for helping !.

Comment: You need to display no numbers found after the loop?? Am I right?

Comment: You want to count the number of amicable numbers found (so increment `liElse` when you print).  If that number is zero after the loop, then print "The numbers are not friends".  Note that it is better to print newlines at the end of outputs, not the beginning.  It helps the messages appear in a timely fashion, amongst other benefits.

Comment: THANKS  Jonathan Leffler, i have fixed it. Thanks a lot!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the following code, using one BOOL var.

```
int liContador1, liContador2;
bool bBreak = true;
for (liContador1 = 1; bBreak && (liContador1 <= liNumeroB); liContador1++)
{
    for (liContador2 = liContador1 + 1; liContador2 <= liNumeroB; liContador2++)
    {
        if (NumerosAmigos(liContador1, liContador2))
        {
            printf("\n%d, %d", liContador1, liContador2);
        }
        else
        {
            bBreak = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!bBreak)
    printf("\nThe numbers are not friends.\n");
```